# How can I get the data from an ajax request to appear inside a div?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, prepend

I am unable to get the `data` from my ajax request to appear inside `<div class="l_p_i_c_w"></div>`. What am I doing wrong? I know the function inside `my_file.php` works, because if I refresh the page, then the data shows up where it should.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_file.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').prepend(data);
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="l_p_w" id="myID">
    <div class="l_p_c">
        <div class="l_p_i_c_w">
       <!-- stuff, or may be empty. This is where I want my ajax data placed. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.l_p_w {
    width:740px;
    min-height:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.l_p_c {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    width:370px;
    top:60px;
}

.l_p_i_c_w {
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm suspecting that it is the CSS, because I've used ajax many times before and never had a problem.

Comment: inspect your div .l_p_i_c_w  with firebug check data coming in it or not, also alert data in success function

Comment: I did ``alert(data)`` and I saw the html that is supposed to be inserted in to the div, but if I use ``...prepend(data)`` it doesn't work. I still can't figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use prepend you would need to wrap your data object in jquery tags like $(data) before appending, as prepend appends children (objects)

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_file.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').prepend($(data));
            }
    });
```

However, if you just want to set the html of the div with the data do this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_file.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').html(data);
        }
});
```

Third Option, try prependTo

http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_file.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        $(data).prependTo($('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w'));
    }
});
```

One last attempt:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_file.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').html(data + $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').html());
            }
    });
```

Comment: There may be other divs inside ``<div class="l_p_i_c_w">``, and I want my ajaxed data to be inserted at the top.

Comment: added a 3rd option, using prependTo

Comment: None of these answers work. They are just different versions of what I have already tried. When I refresh the page, then the data that I tried to ajax into ``<div class="l_p_i_c_w">`` is there, so I know my php works. I still can't get the ajax to work.

Comment: Where does your php page reside in relation to the javascript? Are they on the same domain, subdomain, port, etc? It could be a violation of the Same origin policy... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: It's on the same domain. The jquery script I'm using sends data to my php file, and is then inserted into the database. All of that works fine. It just won't "ajax" the data back to me. I am only able to see that it works when I refresh the page.

Comment: have you checked that the success call is even being called? try logging or alerting the data and see if your code even reaches that point. also, added one last attempt setting the html up top, more flavors of the same thing though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').prepend(data);
```

should be

```
 $('#myID .l_p_c .l_p_i_c_w').html(data);
```

Comment: This would replace everything inside the div, right? I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_file.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        complete: function(jqXHR, settings){
            if (jqXHR.status == 200)
               $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').prepend(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_file.php",
        dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(data) {
     $('div#myID div.l_p_c div.l_p_i_c_w').prepend(data);
});
```

Comment: Unexpected `,` after `dataType`.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) ?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_file.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $(data).prependTo('#myID .l_p_c .l_p_i_c_w');
            }
    });
```

As @rajesh mentioned in his comment to your question, try alerting the data in the success to make sure it's coming back as expected:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_file.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
    });
```